# How to find : $\lim_{x \to 1/4}\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

How to find :

$$\lim_{x \to 1/4}\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt{x}}$$

---

My Try :

$$x-\frac{1}{4}=t \to x=t+\frac{1}{4}$$

And:

$$\tan\pi(t+\frac{1}{4})=\tan(\pi t +\frac{\pi}{4})$$

So we have :

$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1-\tan(\pi t +\frac{\pi}{4})}{2(t+\frac{1}{4})-\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}}$$

but now what ?

Comment: I can do it using nothing but the definition of the derivative (of $\tan(\pi x)$ at $x=1/4$).Would that suffice?

Comment: @Lubin. very nice .

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\frac14}\dfrac{1-\tan\pi x}{2x-\sqrt{x}}
&= \lim_{x\to\frac14}\dfrac{\tan\dfrac{\pi}{4}-\tan\pi x}{2x-\sqrt{x}}\times\dfrac{2x+\sqrt{x}}{2x+\sqrt{x}} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\frac14}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\pi x\right)}{\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cos\pi x}\dfrac{2x+\sqrt{x}}{4x^2-x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\frac14}\frac{\sin\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}-x\right)}{\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\cos\pi x}\dfrac{2x+\sqrt{x}}{-4x(\frac14-x)} \\
&= \lim_{x\to\frac14}\dfrac{\sin\pi\left(\frac{1}{4}-x\right)}{\pi(\frac14-x)} \dfrac{\pi}{-4x\cos\dfrac{\pi}{4}\cos\pi x} (2x+\sqrt{x}) \\
&= \dfrac{\pi}{-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} (\frac12+\frac12) \\
&= \color{blue}{-2\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: I can’t say I exactly see your illumination of $\tan(\pi/4)-\tan(\pi  x)$ as that expression in sine and cosines. Could you stick in an extra step or two?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $g(x)=\tan(\pi x)$, then $g'(x)=\pi\sec^2(\pi x)$, and $g'(1/4)=\pi(\sqrt2)^2=2\pi$. But from the definition of the derivative,
$$
g'(1/4)=\lim_{x\to1/4}\frac{\tan(\pi x)-1}{x-\frac14}=-4\lim_{x\to1/4}\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{4x-1}\,,
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{x\to1/4}\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{4x-1}=-\pi/2\,.
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt x}&=\frac{\bigl(1-\tan(\pi x)\bigr)(2x+\sqrt x\,)}{4x^2-x}\\
&=\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{4x-1}\cdot\frac{2x+\sqrt x}{x}\,,
\end{align}
in which product the left-hand factor has limit $-\pi/2$ at $1/4$, while the right-hand factor has value at $1/4$ equal to $4$. Thus the desired limit is $-2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1-\tan(\pi t +\frac{\pi}{4})}{2(t+\frac{1}{4})-\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}}=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1-\frac{\tan\pi t+1}{1-\tan\pi t}}{\left(2\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}-1\right)\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}}=$$
$$=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{-4\tan\pi t}{2\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}-1}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{-4\sin\pi t\left(2\sqrt{t+\frac{1}{4}}+1\right)}{4t}=-2\pi\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin\pi t}{\pi t}=-2\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know about Taylor expansions, this is a practical solution.

Built aroud $x=\frac 14$, you have
$$\tan(\pi x)=1+2 \pi  \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)+2 \pi ^2
   \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^3\right)$$
$$\sqrt x=\frac{1}{2}+\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)-\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-
   \frac{1}{4}\right)^3\right)$$ All of the above make
$$\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{-2 \pi  \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)-2 \pi ^2
   \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^3\right) } { \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^3\right)}$$
$$\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt{x}}=\frac{-2 \pi  -2 \pi ^2
   \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right) } { 1+\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)}$$ which shws the limit.

If you continue with long division, you should get
$$\frac{1-\tan(\pi x)}{2x-\sqrt{x}}=-2 \pi -2\pi\left( \pi -1\right)
   \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right)$$ which shows how is approached the limit.